# How can you solve algebraic equations (eg, $10x+y=3xy$, knowing that $x$ and $y$ are integers between $1$ and $9$) without trial and error?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Often, I will come across questions which involve equations that need to be solved by trial and error.

For example, the equation
$$10x+y=3xy$$
In this case, the question provides us that $x\neq y$ and that $x=1, 2, 3, \ldots, 9$ and $y=1, 2, 3, \ldots, 9$. How can we solve this question without any trial and error?

Comment: Welcome to Math SE. See [Simon's Favorite Factoring Trick](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Simon%27s_Favorite_Factoring_Trick) for one available method that helps to minimize the number of cases to check.

Answer (score 4):

Agreed with another answer that there is no single trick, but a range of different tricks that may help.

---

One idea you may like here: $10x+y=3xy$ is equivalent to:

$$y=\frac{10x}{3x-1}$$

so as $3x-1$ divides $10x=3(3x-1)+(x+3)$, it must divide $x+3$ and so $3x-1\le x+3$ giving you $x\le 2$.

Now see that $x=1$ gives $y=5$ and $x=2$ gives $y=4$, so $(1,5)$ and $(2,4)$ are the solutions.

---

A slightly different execution of the same idea: if you write the expression as:

$$x=\frac{y}{3y-10}$$

you will have $3y-10>0$ i.e. $y>\frac{10}{3}$, i.e. $y\ge 4$ (being an integer). However, this means that $x=\frac{y}{3y-10}\le 2$ because this is equivalent to $y\le 6y-20$ i.e. $y\ge 4$ (which we have just proven). What remains is, as in the previous proof, to check $x=1$ and $x=2$.

---

A different idea: from $10x+y=3xy$ we conclude that $x\mid y=x(3y-10)$ and that $y\mid 10x=y(3x-1)$. Now set $y=kx$, we have that $kx\mid 10x$, i.e. $k\mid 10$. The positive divisors of $10$ are: $k=1,2,5,10$. Because $y=x$ is forbidden and $y=10x$ will make $y$ too big, the only cases we need to try are $y=2x$ and $y=5x$. Substituting into the original equation and cancelling $x>0$:

- $y=2x$ means that $12x=6x^2$ i.e. $x=2, y=4$
- $y=5x$ means that $15x=15x^2$ i.e. $x=1, y=5$

Answer (score 2):

As per my knowledge there is not any fixed method to solve such equations in integers and each problem should be treated on its own merit.In this case you can reduce your steps by observing certain things like
$$x+y=3(xy+3x)$$
which gives x+y must be divisible by 3.Also note that
$$y=x(y-10x)$$
which gives x is a factor of y.Moreover note that x cannot be equal to y

This limits the possibilities to (1,2),(1,5),(1,8),(2,4),(3,6),(3,9),(4,8).A quick check gives (1,5),(2,4) are the only possibilities